# jquery only worked while debugging?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have following code, the autocomplete only work with the first character, after that, it stopped doing anything. But if run while debugging with chrome dev tool (few breakpoints here and there), it works fine. So maybe there is a timing issue?

The url is mvc controller action returning JsonResult using entity framework, which is called every time in debugging, but only for the first letter without debugging

Any help appreciated!

```
$(function () {

    $("#customer").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = $("#input").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/AutoCompleteCustomer",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.CUST_NM, value: item.CUST_NM };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            })},
            minLength: 1
    });

// More code beyond...

});
```

**Update**: I should point out I am using polymer component paper-input-autocomplete: https://customelements.io/rodo1111/paper-input-autocomplete/
Maybe that has something to do with it.

With this component the request in jason looks like following, that's why I cannot use it:
JSON.stringify(request);
"{"term":"\n    \n      \n    \n\n    \n    \n\n    \n       \n    \n\n    \n      \n\n      \n        Customer Name\n      \n\n      \n    \n\n    \n      \n      \n    \n\n    \n      \n    \n\n    Customer Name is required!\n  \n    \n  \n  \n      \n  \n    \n    \n    \n    \n\n    \n      \n    \n  \n  "}"

**UPDATE**: Switched to another component. Thanks to everyone trying to help!

Comment: What errors if any appear in the the console. Please include an example of the data that AJAX would receive for testing. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Put break point near controller and check wether it is hitting on each key press

Comment: Open your browser console and see whether you are getting any errors.

Comment: First of all, I'd debate the authenticity of  document.querySelector('#input').value; .. is this being updated each time you enter in a value? Second of all, why aren't you using the "request" object. You can debug that and see if "request.term" has a value inside that.. or investigate the request object and all its properties. I think that's where the problem truly resides. It is possible that the debug mode provides an updated term.

Comment: No error in console window. data returned from controller: 
"[{"CUST_NM":"Sabrina V Craigmile"},{"CUST_NM":"Sarah S Raasoch"}]"

Comment: @Venkata Krishna Reddy, break point in controller only got hit for the first letter if no-debugging mode, but every time in debugging mode

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are setting your `term` wrong.

Tested in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/eyt3jvgk/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  Customer:
  <input type="text" id="customer" />
</div>
```

**jQuery UI**

```
$(function() {
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      //var term = document.querySelector('#input').value;
      var term = request.term;
      $.ajax({
        //url: "/Home/AutoCompleteCustomer",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: term,
          json: JSON.stringify([{
            CUSTNAME: "John"
          }, {
            CUSTNAME: "Sally"
          }])
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            return {
              label: item.CUSTNAME,
              value: item.CUSTNAME
            };
          }))
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 1
  });
});
```

With psuedo data, I was able to get results. The `request` is the data entered in the field. Did you need to get data from another field? If so, this would be:

```
var term = $("#input").val();
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

If your data results are:

```
[
  {
    "CUST_NM":"Sabrina V Craigmile"
  },
  {
    "CUST_NM":"Sarah S Raasoch"
  }
]
```

Then `item.CUSTNAME` would not be able to find a result and would be `null`.

Try:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  response($.map(data, function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return {
      label: item.CUST_NM,
      value: item.CUST_NM
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Haha, I just commented about that issue at the same time you posted this answer. You have more confidence than I do that this is the problem :-D

Comment: @sksallaj it's all smoke and mirrors. My day job is phone support, and I am able to read between the line pretty well. Also, once I put his example code into a test env., I was able to better understand what OP was trying to do and just went toward a solution that worked with the limited info I had. Got to start somewhere. ;)

Comment: @Twisty, thanks but that did not solve my problem (better syntax though so I updated with your var term = $("#input").val()). Like I said, it is working fine in debugging mode, so parameter passing to controller was working

Comment: @startover You're not calling the right objects maybe, from your other comment: `[{"CUST_NM":"Sabrina V Craigmile"},{"CUST_NM":"Sarah S Raasoch"}]`, so `item.CUSTNAME` would fail.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be CUST_NM all over. I updated the code in post

Comment: @startover if you cannot use stringify, and are calling the term from `$("#input").val()`, how is this text field updated? What is it's value? How should we replicate the issue for testing?

Comment: Thanks @Twisty, $("#input").val() give me the value typed in that field. I think you can replicate my problem by using the same component downloaded from link below (need polymer), and put it in html file like <paper-input-autocomplete id="customer" name="customer" label="Customer Name" required auto-validate error-message="Customer Name is required!"></paper-input-autocomplete>;  https://customelements.io/rodo1111/paper-input-autocomplete/